# How to handle when Application goes to background

Tags: android, server

I am working on application, where in am getting a tasks  from server and then user evaluate through Mobile Application(just like a quiz Application).

During Evaluation of Tasks, if the user presses home button then app goes to background. And when user back to application from recent background applications, then Application started from Splash screen.

I am confused that what price of code should I add, so that when user back to Application, then previous state must be shown to the user??

Comment: make a base activity and extends your all activities with BaseActivity instead of actiivty and extend your Base Activity with AppCompactActivity

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i have extended all of my activities classes to AppCompatActivity... According to your Answer the purpose same ? is not

Comment: in first Step make an Activity name BaseActivity Extens with AppCompactActivity and than all your other activities extend with Base Activity except splash activity do this and let me know i will guide you further

Comment: I implement what you are saying then let you know...

Comment: I implimented the same logic as you said, but the problem is not solved. splash screen in is extended with Activity, and all other classes are extended with BaseActivity. What should i do now

Comment: i am gining a class below in answer you just copy this class and paste it with same name i am sending you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy this class further i will tell you what to do

```
public class Foreground implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

public static final long CHECK_DELAY = 50;
public static final String TAG = Foreground.class.getName();

public interface Listener {

    public void onBecameForeground();

    public void onBecameBackground();

}

private static Foreground instance;

private boolean foreground = false, paused = true;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private List<Listener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener>();
private Runnable check;

/**
 * Its not strictly necessary to use this method - _usually_ invoking
 * get with a Context gives us a path to retrieve the Application and
 * initialise, but sometimes (e.g. in test harness) the ApplicationContext
 * is != the Application, and the docs make no guarantees.
 *
 * @param application
 * @return an initialised Foreground instance
 */
public static Foreground init(Application application){
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Foreground();
        application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(instance);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static Foreground get(Application application){
    if (instance == null) {
        init(application);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static Foreground get(Context ctx){
    if (instance == null) {
        Context appCtx = ctx.getApplicationContext();
        if (appCtx instanceof Application) {
            init((Application)appCtx);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Foreground is not initialised and " +
                        "cannot obtain the Application object");
    }
    return instance;
}

public static Foreground get(){
    if (instance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Foreground is not initialised - invoke " +
                        "at least once with parameterised init/get");
    }
    return instance;
}

public boolean isForeground(){
    return foreground;
}

public boolean isBackground(){
    return !foreground;
}

public void addListener(Listener listener){
    listeners.add(listener);
}

public void removeListener(Listener listener){
    listeners.remove(listener);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    paused = false;
    boolean wasBackground = !foreground;
    foreground = true;

    if (check != null)
        handler.removeCallbacks(check);

    if (wasBackground){
        Log.i(TAG, "went foreground");
        for (Listener l : listeners) {
            try {
                l.onBecameForeground();
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Listener threw exception!", exc);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "still foreground");
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    paused = true;
    if (check != null)
        handler.removeCallbacks(check);

    handler.postDelayed(check = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (foreground && paused) {
                foreground = false;
                Log.i(TAG, "went background");
                for (Listener l : listeners) {
                    try {
                        l.onBecameBackground();
                    } catch (Exception exc) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Listener threw exception!", exc);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "still foreground");
            }
        }
    }, CHECK_DELAY);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {}
```

}

add this in onCreate of year Application Class

```
    Foreground foreground = Foreground.init(this);

    final Foreground.Listener myListener = new Foreground.Listener()
    {
        public void onBecameForeground()
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "FOREGROUND");
        }

        public void onBecameBackground()
        {
            //registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyLifecycleHandler());

                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN").putExtra("some_msg", "I will be sent!");
                sendBroadcast(i);


        }
    };

    foreground.addListener(myListener);
```

add this code in onCreate of your Base Activity ok ?

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            "android.intent.action.MAIN");

    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            //extract our message from intent
            String msg_for_me = intent.getStringExtra("some_msg");
            //log our message value
            Log.i("InchooTutorial", msg_for_me);



                finish();


        }
    };
    //registering our receiver
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

not this this is your override onDestroy method copy outside the oncreate

```
  @Override
   protected void onDestroy()
    {
     super.onDestroy();
      unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have copied this class to my project. Now what should i suppose to do ?

Comment: make a activity named Application and  extend with it Application . do you have already Applcation class in your project?

Comment: Yes i have already in my project, i have used it to check internet Connection method and broadcast receiver in Application class.

Comment: thats good now i am going to edit my answer above you just copy the code and write code in onCreate of Application Class

Comment: I added to onCreate() of Application, but giving me error on CommonMethods. ? i cant import such method

Comment: Done, Error are removed, Now can i test my application or further changes are required to add?

Comment: i added your code, to oncreate() of BaseActivity, but one more thing when i extends all other activities to BaseActivity then it give me an error that oncreate method is already overrided...

Comment: I have resolved all the error, should in run the application to test ?

Comment: Application did not worked... Same problem, Should i add some more code or any other changes ?

Comment: only problem is your broadcast is not calling

Comment: add debugger in onBecomeBackground Function in Application class and also in onRecieve of BaseActivity and tell me where the debugger attach

Comment: i think i have missed to include receiver in menifist file?

Comment: no need to add in manifest , but you can try by adding as you already use receiver

Comment: y attach debugger on Foreground activity and check either debugger attached or not in onResume and onPause of Foreground activity

Answer (score 0):

Overide the methods onStop(), onPause(), onResume() in your main activity.